# Durable Azure Functions suddenly escapes string input parameters for activity function when using nameof()

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, .net-8.0

I am upgrading my function app from from NET 7 to NET 8. I very quickly ran into problems, and currently I am debugging a supposed change in behaviour when passing a string input from an durable orchestrator function into an activity function.

Below is the code that is failing.. please pay attention to the input parameter. I am using the `nameof()` operator on a interface member. Within the function this is the single input. I then switch on the input and throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException if the input is not in the expected range.

Before upgrading the code worked without a problem. Now its throwing. When debugging I found out, that the input's value is **not** `"FxbmSendTemplatesApproval"` anymore but rather `"\"FxbmSendTemplatesApproval\""`. Imho there is additional serialization which was not there previously.

[image]

Here's the invocation in the orchestrator:

```cs
var approvalRecipients = await ctx.CallActivityAsync<Recipients>(nameof(GetRecipients), input: nameof(IVerteilerService.FxbmSendTemplatesApproval));
```

Here's the activity function:

```cs
public class GetRecipients(IVerteilerService verteiler)
{
    [Function(nameof(GetRecipients))]
    public async Task<Recipients> Run([ActivityTrigger] string verteilerName)
    {
        var x =1 ;
        return verteilerName switch
        {
            // ...
            nameof(verteiler.FxbmSendTemplatesApproval) => await verteiler.FxbmSendTemplatesApproval(),
            // ...
            _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
        };
    }
}
```

Is this to be expected? I mean it worked before upgrading :/ To me it seems, as though only objects are now expected as function inputs. Then there would be no double-serialization I guess. Any help or insights on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nvm, I was to quick to post. This is already adressed as a bug on [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/2677). The proposed solution is to downgrad the DF extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue and its true that by downgrading the package worked:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask
```

Calling :

```
string rithpar = "Rithwik Bojja";
rithpar = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), rithpar);
```

Activity Function:

```
 [Function(nameof(SayHello))]
 public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string rith, FunctionContext executionContext)
 {
     ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("SayHello");
     logger.LogInformation("Saying hello to {name}.", rith);
     return $"Hello {rith}!";
 }
```

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

Refer this [GitHub Ticket](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/2677).